# Wordpress | Keep getting same error over and over

Tags: php, wordpress

i did move a website to another server now i keep getting the same error over and over again and the page will freeze. But when i put the backup of the website on xampp it does work?

This is the code that repeats itself

```
Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/home/lapermanen/domains/lapermanence.vdbc.nl/public_html/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home/cyclosport/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/usr/local/php56/lib/:/usr/local/php54/lib/:/usr/local/php55/lib/:/usr/local/lib/php/) in /var/home/cyclosport/domains/cyclosportive.coersonline.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 158
```

Thanks.

HTACCESS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you paste your .htaccess here?

Comment: @serverliving.com # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script is not within the allowed locations for PHP scripts in your system.

You can fix this by modifying `open_basedir` setting in PHP.INI, or you can move your scripts to one of the directories listed in the error message.

Comment: The first hit on Google for "open_basedir" tells what this feature is...